# PHP - while loop + fgetcsv to remote file - any way to avoid opening and closing each time?

Tags: php, foreach, while-loop, fopen, fgetcsv

I have a peice of PHP script which loops through a directory and looks for filenames present in both the directory and column 1-6 in a CSV file. If it finds one, it checks column 0 of the same row to see if a "Primary" version of the file exists. If it does, it deletes the "secondary" file it's evaluating.

```
<?php
chdir('../'); // Go up a directory
$fileArray = array_values(preg_grep('/^(\.|\.\.|Removed)$/', scandir('.') , PREG_GREP_INVERT));

foreach ($fileArray as $thisFile)
{
    if (preg_match('/^.*?(?=\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$)/', $thisFile, $thisFileNoExtension)) // Preg Match the file extension
    {
        $thisFileNoExtension = $thisFileNoExtension[0]; // Give the file extension it's own string
    }
    else
    {
        $thisFileNoExtension = $thisFile; // If it's a directory
    }

    // Let the user know what file is being evaluated
    echo "\033[35m{$thisFileNoExtension} ... \033[0m";

    $csvManualRegionDupes = fopen("--- HYPERLINK TO REMOTE GOOGLE SHEETS CSV FILE ---", "r");

    while ($csvRow = fgetcsv($csvManualRegionDupes))
    {
        if (in_array($thisFileNoExtension, array_slice($csvRow, 1, 6)))
        {
            $fileCheck = preg_grep('/' . preg_quote($csvRow[0]) . '/', $fileArray); //
            if ($fileCheck)
            {
                echo "\033[36mis on the Manual Region Dupes list and primary version detected. Moved to Removed folder.\n\033[0m";
                rename("$thisFile", "Removed/$thisFile");
            }
            else
            {
                echo "\033[31mis on the Manual Region Dupes list but primary version is missing. Kept for now.\n\033[0m";
                continue 2;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose($csvManualRegionDupes);

echo "\033[34mScanned and is OK.\n\033[0m";
}
?>
```

It used to work well, however now that I have put `$csvManualRegionDupes` to point towards a remote file, it's taking a long time to get through the loop. I think this is beacuse `fopen` and `fclose` is being run for every `$thisFile`. Is there a way of opening this remote file only once and still completing the `foreach` and `while` loops properly? I have tried tinkering with it and I keep breaking the functionality.

Many thanks!

Comment: If you are reading a network file that will work based on client internet speed. won't work when there is not a network. I suggest search for an SVG file and place it in your asset folder and call it, that won't trouble you.

Comment: If I undertand your code properly, no.  You have an array of file names, you process one at a time (using `foreach`), then use a `while` to read line after line of that file.  There is no way to read a file without doing an open first.  And I would not recommend doing an open on all files at once.  Looks like the slow response time is related to network latency, google access time, ...

Comment: OK, thanks! I guess I can try and download the CSV into a temp folder and go from there!